# Is there a way to automate a C# .Net Application without original source code

Tags: c#, automation, ui-automation

Is there a way to automate a C# .Net Application without original source code?

I want to be able to write UI tests for a C# .Net Windows Form Application. But I only have the exe file for the application. I don't have the original source code. I don't know if having the original source is necessary.

I was also wondering, how does Microsoft test their own windows applications. For example, I doubt they have manual testers clicking around when testing Microsoft Word or even the calculator app built into windows. I'm sure they have automated tests for that.

Comment: If you check through some of the open-source solutions that Microsoft provide, you'll notice that a large quantity of them are using unit testing, check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-nunit

Comment: You don't need source code for UI testing, you can google for available libraries for UI testing and choose one of them

Comment: There are tons of UI test automation tools. Just google "WinForms UI test automation".

Comment: You can test desktop applications by writing "robot" code that takes control of the mouse and keyboard and simulates human interaction. It's not necessarily easy and can be error prone.

Answer (score 1):

Well, atleast MS introduced the UIAutomation Framwork, which is faced to users for automated tests or projects like screen readers and more. More information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview

That Framework is pretty neat when it comes to automate managed code UIs because accessing UI controls and invoking user inputs are pretty easy.

Comment: That neat framework doesnt work for Win Forms only WPF

Comment: That is wrong. Often used it with and for Winform!

Comment: You sure? Documentation says WPF only. But I personally never used it on winforms though.

Comment: @Hefaistos68 then you should read correctly: `Microsoft UI Automation is the new accessibility framework for Microsoft Windows, available on all operating systems that support Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF).` says, it is available on ALL plattforsm SUPPORTING WPF. So, you can use it in Winforms aswell.

Comment: This phrase is kinda open to interpretation, but reading deeper into the topic somewhere else one finds: ´Microsoft UI Automation support for standard controls in applications developed for the WPF, Win32, and Windows Forms frameworks´, so yes, you are right.